# Will analog camera's timestamp work with remjet film?

Tags: film, 35mm

Will analog 35mm camera's quartz timestamp work with motion pictures remjet film? 
I know that the carbon layer is last so will the timestamp be able to imprint the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested on Vision3 500T and the timestamp is working. So there is no difference between remjet and normal film.